# attaching a usb printer to hyper-v virtual machines

Tags: printing, driver, virtualization, hyper-v

I have a printer that doesn't have the driver for my windows server 2008, and I tried other platform drivers but they did not work either. Hyper-V is installed in the server and I want to know if there is a way so that I could attach my printer USB device to virtual machines (that have drivers for my printer) runing in hyper-v so that i could print.

Comment: This probably should be moved to ServerFault.  That being said, the host system creating the job will always need a driver, you should be able to find a compatible driver the generates similar PCL, PS etc.  What printer is it?

Comment: of course I am not aiming to find a driver for it, but i want to attach it to a virtual machine with a compatible OS. I could do this in vmware workstation 8.0

Comment: I must be missing something. What sort of printer is is? Why can't you connect it to server 2008? In the end the application, driver, communication method and device are all separate components and don't need to be specific to the device but rather best fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyper-V cannot redirect USB on host machine into the virtual machines. VMWare workstation/player and VirtualBox can do this. But it's not recommended to install Hyper-V hypervisor with other virtualization software on the same machine.